# IDEA module missing maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have been using [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for a while now, but I always opened one instance for each module that I am working on, so for example:

I have one `data-access` module and one `service` module and
`data-access` is a dependency of `service` module.

When I work on those I have one `IntelliJ IDEA` instance for each.

So I wanted to have them all on a single instance as 2 modules, so here is what I did:

I created a parent `pom.xml` file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rodrigosasaki</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>data-access</module>
        <module>service</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

After that I created a new IDEA `project` based on this pom, and it opened the 2 modules correctly.

But I can't build them. If I look in `Project Settings > Libraries` I don't see the maven dependencies.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly error message you get?
Did you try to build them outside of your IDE with maven? Just try to navigate to the parent pom from the command line an try: mvn clean compile

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine outside of intellij, so I'm pretty sure this is related to the IDE. Basically all I want is to have all modules in a single IDE instance, like I used to do on eclipse